# Facebook image processing technique

Tags: image-processing, user-interface, x-facebook-platform

Well, i wonder, what compression procession processes they are using..
I uploaded a test image of 2.3mb and suddenly downloaded it

It was only only 92 kbs, what the heck, only 92 kb's
and the thumbnail was only 11 kbs..

How this all is done and what algorithms are utilized.. how do i do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, the file size decrease is probably due primarily to just old-fashioned downsampling.  Images on facebook are sized to be viewed on part of a screen, but not much larger.

For instance, I uploaded a picture that was 3456x2304 (3.2MB) which is 7,962,624 pixels.  This was downsized by facebook to 960x602 (85kB) which is only 577,920 pixels.  That only about 1/14th the total number of pixels.

This probably explains the majority of the difference, but it also looks like they are using the [sRGB color profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB), which can reduce file sizes.

One other possibility is that most JPEG encoders have a quality setting.  They may be using a lower quality setting than that of the original.

Comment: It depends on what application you are creating the image with.  Some applications may not expose this, but I know Photoshop and Gimp do.  They usually have a selector come up when you are saving or exporting the image to set the quality.

Comment: But here we are talking about automated processing as... we upload it, some automation work upon it and right then it is available for views to the users

Comment: Whatever JPEG encoding library you use should have some kind of setting for the quality or compression parameter.  What language and jpeg library are you using?

Comment: As a language, i am working with php, and as far as the jpeg library is concerned, i am trying my hands on Image Magick